# Codeigniter language not change with language class

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

i am develop a website multilanguage italian and english with Codeigniter, but the output is only English language of default when i change to italian not change. I don't see any errors in output. I will post my code at trying now.

My Controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function index($language = null)
    {
        if($language == 'en')
        {
            $this->lang->load('home', 'english');
            $line_lang = 'english';
        }

        else
        {
            $this->lang->load('home', 'italian');
            $line_lang = 'italiano';
        }

        $data = array();

        $data['set_lang'] = $line_lang;
        $this->load->view('home_view.php', $data);
    }




}
```

View

```
$this->lang->line('lingua_sito');
```

Into english fonder home_lang.php

```
$lang['lingua_sito'] = 'Hello Word';
```

Into italian folder contain

```
<?php

$lang['lingua_sito'] = 'Ciao Mondo';
```

Someone have any suggestions? thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I just test your code its working fine for me. Can you check your are not loading the language again anywhere else ie `view, post_controller hook`. Also try a clean controller and view and load only one language without any `if` to see you are able to load the language